# How can I determine max size heap can grow to in Mac OS X?

Tags: c, macos, size, heap-memory

Say, for instance, I have 16GB of memory and am doing a very large amount of dynamic memory allocation in C (just for testing, nothing in particular). How can I determine how large the heap will be able to grow to, to accommodate my `calloc`'s?

Comment: Why do you want to? It is hadly possible to do that. Just allocate whatever memory you need and handle faults.

Comment: I'm just curious about approximately what % of total RAM is available for the heap on average and thought I could look at my own system. I was thinking in the future if I'm working on something with a low amount of RAM it would be useful to have an idea of how much the heap could use off the top of my head.

Comment: You are on a multiprocessing, multi-CPU system with hundeds of concurrent processes. Well, that question has been asked multiple times before. Do some research!

Comment: I can't find a previous post that addresses it or a google link. Maybe I don't know what the proper search terms should be.

Comment: Open the *"Launchpad"*, find the *"Activity Monitor"*, and click on the *"Memory"* button at the top of the window. At the bottom of the window, it will show the memory size, and the memory used.

Comment: can the heap use all the way up to (memory size - memory used) or less than that?

Comment: google: "stack overflow determine size of heap" -> 3rd result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687274/size-of-stack-and-heap-memory (already a dup) - Are people really not even able to google anymore?

Comment: Bear in mind that items in the process address space, like the stack and the heap, are part of *virtual memory*.  They might reside in RAM, they might not.  On a lightly loaded system it might all be in RAM, on an over subscribed system that is page-faulting like mad then only the minimum working set might be in RAM.  RAM (as opposed to virtual memory) usage is very difficult to predict.

Comment: Due to virtual memory, you can use more than (memory size - memory used), but when you do that, the program slows down, and the hard drive heats up (gets used a lot). I would leave a margin of at least 500MB to avoid thrashing the hard drive.

Comment: Why not just use the `heap` utility?